# Can I have only the date from datetime object in tick label matplotlib?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

If I have a pandas dataframe such as this:

```
                     col1    col2  
time                                                                        
2014-10-01 11:49:32  1      193.75   
2014-10-02 10:32:51  2      62.26   
2014-10-11 15:19:03  3      96.68   
...and so forth
```

and would like to plot these values for each date.

within the plot, to get the datetime labels, I would use

```
xticks2 = pd.date_range(start=df.iloc[0,0],end=df.iloc[-1,0], freq='7D', normalize=True)    
ax2 = axes2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=range(7), interval=1)) 
ax2 = plt.xticks(xticks2,xticks2, rotation=0)
```

But this gives the horrendously long label, i.e. 2014-10-01 11:49:32. Is there a way to achieve a label just like 2014-10-01 (**date without time**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new column just for the date and plot against that.

```
df['Dates'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: x.date().isoformat())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your existing code

```
axes2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Not doing anything :(